# Understanding C++ Code written with templates and class inheritance

Tags: c++

I came across the below piece of code in a header file.

```
template <int x, template <typename T> class Car,
          typename DOC, typename COMMON,
          typename filter = imp::Filter>
class CurrentClass
    : public imp::base<
          x, Car, DOC,
          CurrentClass<x, Car, DOC, COMMON>, Filter> {
public:
  COMMON *common;
  CurrentClass(Connection &cnt, COMMON *common_)
      : imp::base<
            x, Car, DOC,
            CurrentClass<x, Car, DOC, COMMON>,
            Filter>(cnt),
       common(common_) {}
};
```

Can someone please explain the different parts of this code in terms of templates and class inheritance?

According to my understanding `CurrentClass` inherits from the base class declared in imp class.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't ever post images of code. Post code as *text*.

Comment: *Can someone please explain the different parts of this code in terms of templates and class inheritance* -- That is a job for a good C++ book.

Comment: This is an example of a fairly advanced use of C++ templates. To fully explain what's happening here requires, probably, six months to a year of learning how templates work, beforehand, before starting to understand how templates are used here. Obviously, explaining a year's worth of learning C++ templates is not something that can be done in a paragraph or two on stackoverflow.com. The best way for you to learn this is to continue following the methodical, guided approach that your C++ textbook uses to present this material, until you understand this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik can you please suggest a good c++ book.

Comment: See stackoverflow.com's [list of C++ textbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of noise in this code and as mentioned, it is quite advanced, but google the points I note below. There are several distinct things I can point out:

1.

```
template <int x, template <typename T> class Car,
      typename DOC, typename COMMON,
      typename filter = imp::Filter>
```

The "int x" part require that argument to be an integer

The "template <typename T> class Car" is known as a template-template. It's essentially pulling the template-type out of a type. Example: std::vector<int> - the template-template is "int".

Typename filter = imp::filter
Is just a default template argument and is optional.

2.
You will notice that the class CurrentClass inherits from some base class imp::Base with some template arguments: x, car, doc. You will then notice it passes *itself* + it's template arguments *to the base class. This is known as CRTP, and it's a way to create c++ virtuals, using templates! Very powerful stuff.

```
class CurrentClass
: public imp::base<
      x, Car, DOC,
      CurrentClass<x, Car, DOC, COMMON>, Filter> {
```

I've highlighted (with square brackets) the important bits of the CRTP below:

```
class CurrentClass
[: public imp::base<]
      x, Car, DOC,
      [CurrentClass<x, Car, DOC, COMMON>, Filter>] {
```

The constructor is just initialising the base class. Which is normal code.